# JUNG: Paint graph on existing JPanel

Tags: java, graph, jung

I am starting with JUNG and I get to draw a graph in the Jpanel of a newly created JFrame, but I am unable to paint the same Graph in an existing Panel of the program I am developing.

The function I use is this:

```
private void demoGraph() {
        // Graph<V, E> where V is the type of the vertices and E is the type of the edges
        // Note showing the use of a SparseGraph rather than a SparseMultigraph
        Graph<Integer, String> g = new SparseGraph<>();
        // Add some vertices. From above we defined these to be type Integer.
        g.addVertex((Integer) 1);
        g.addVertex((Integer) 2);
        g.addVertex((Integer) 3);
        // g.addVertex((Integer)1);  // note if you add the same object again nothing changes
        // Add some edges. From above we defined these to be of type String
        // Note that the default is for undirected edges.
        g.addEdge("Edge-A", 1, 2); // Note that Java 1.5 auto-boxes primitives
        g.addEdge("Edge-B", 2, 3);

        // Layout<V, E>, VisualizationComponent<V,E>
        Layout<Integer, String> layout = new CircleLayout(g);
        layout.setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        VisualizationViewer<Integer, String> vv = new VisualizationViewer<>(layout);
        vv.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 350));
        // Setup up a new vertex to paint transformer...
        Transformer<Integer, Paint> vertexPaint = new Transformer<Integer, Paint>() {
            @Override
            public Paint transform(Integer i) {
                return Color.GREEN;
            }
        };
        // Set up a new stroke Transformer for the edges
        float dash[] = {10.0f};
        final Stroke edgeStroke = new BasicStroke(1.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT,
                BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER, 10.0f, dash, 0.0f);
        Transformer<String, Stroke> edgeStrokeTransformer = new Transformer<String, Stroke>() {
            @Override
            public Stroke transform(String s) {
                return edgeStroke;
            }
        };
        vv.getRenderContext().setVertexFillPaintTransformer(vertexPaint);
        vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeStrokeTransformer(edgeStrokeTransformer);
        vv.getRenderContext().setVertexLabelTransformer(new ToStringLabeller());
        vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeLabelTransformer(new ToStringLabeller());
        vv.getRenderer().getVertexLabelRenderer().setPosition(Position.CNTR);


        // paint on a JPanel: NOT WORKING
        GraphZoomScrollPane panel = new GraphZoomScrollPane(vv);
        panel.setSize(this.graphPanel.getWidth(), this.graphPanel.getHeight());
        BorderLayout panelMapLayout = new BorderLayout();
        panel.setLayout(panelMapLayout);
        panel.setVisible(true);
        this.graphPanel.add(panel);
        this.graphPanel.revalidate();
        this.graphPanel.repaint();

        // Paint on a new JFrame: perfectly working
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple Graph View 2");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(vv);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Some guidance here is much appreciated.

Comment: You don't describe the actual problem you're having.  What are you seeing and what are you expecting?

Comment: Sorry, I need to display the Graph in a JPanel I already have in mu GUI, not in a new JFrame, like all examples show

Comment: I understand, generally, what you want to do.  What is not clear is what is failing.  All you say is "unable to paint".  In any case, there's nothing special about the JFrame that the examples use, so I expect there's probably something subtle about how you're setting that up.  I suggest trying to make your example as simple as possible--and as similar as possible to a working sample--and see if you can figure out what the difference is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've forgotten to add the GUI panel. See:

```
frame.getContentPane().add(vv);
```

should be:

```
this.graphPanel.add(vv);
frame.getContentPane().add(this.graphPanel);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the BorderLayout, I dont know why, but it is the issue:

```
BorderLayout panelMapLayout = new BorderLayout();
panel.setLayout(panelMapLayout);
```